# Closing log file when browser closed

Tags: java, log4j

I am creating log file for my web application. I am able to create log file with time-stamp. But my requirement is,i want to close my log file when browser closed.  i was trying it for long time.i could not get it.Please help to complete this n tell which method i need to follow.

Comment: i think you are a bit confused with your requirement. closing the browser has nothing to do with the log file. when you access your app from the browser logs are being written behind the scene. so your opening and closing dont matter its your app you should be concerned

Comment: what happens if you have 5 users in different browsers?

Comment: I think your requirement is to log browser close action.